# Docker Is there a possibility to restart CMD instruction?

Tags: docker

I have a very simple scenario.

I have some Dockerfile where CMD instruction starts up JETTY. 
After some tests performed I need to restart JETTY due to the change in my test data.

And I cannot restart JETTY process due to the docker is single process application. 
What will be the proper solution for that?

Thanks
Regards, Sergii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could proceed, depending on how often you'll need to restart Jetty.

1. use `docker restart` on the container. This will re-run the command or entrypoint, and it can be automated. Or ...
2. use `docker exec -it /bin/bash` to enter the container and manually restart JETTY. Useful for when you want to interact with it more and debug, but not a good practice for production. or
3. Configure a [supervisor](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/) or similar within the container to monitor for when content changes and automatically restart Jetty. This is a pretty common practice even though it breaks the "one process" idea. Alternatively you could add this kind of monitor on the outside of the container (on the host) and use it to automate 1) above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, with the 3rd solution I can restart jetty as a normal process without touching "main" process supervisor?

Comment: If you use `supervisord`, you can restart subprocesses in several ways without touching the `supervisord` process, yes. My answer was probably too short to be implementable, but I don't know how the test data is changing. Is there a way to detect that from within the container? If so, you can add a second process under `supervisord` to watch for that change and then that second process can talk to `supervisord` to restart JETTY.

Comment: Yes, there is a way to detect. Testdata change is totally under control and I can trigger JETTY restart myself from the test framework. But only curious about a way of communication with supervisor. How should I talk to it? Through docker exec? Thanks